# Trying to include Strong Name dll's to for level 2 security transparency model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, dll, strong-named-key

My 4.0 MVC app that renders a PDF View to screen. It all works on my dev box but generates a security violation from the host provider environment. To compensate, I added [AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers] and [SecurityCritical] attributes on controller. Only now, two of my nuget packages will not compile because they are not strong name compliant. So when I try the following steps to make them strongly named, I end up with a runtime error. Any suggestions appreciated.

Steps to strong name nuget dlls.

```
1) ldasm /all /out=Rotativa.il Rotativa.dll
2) sn -k Rotativa.snk
3) ilasm /dll /key=Rotativa.snk Rotativa.il
```

Runtime Error:
{"Attempt by security transparent method 'my_App. M v c Application. Application_Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.Optimization.Bundle Table.get_Bundles()' failed.\n\n Assembly 'my_App, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is marked with the 'Allow Partially Trusted Callers Attribute', and uses the level 2 security transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in 'Allow Partially Trusted Callers Attribute'assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception."}

Attempt by security transparent method 'my_App. M v c Application.Application_Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.Optimization.Bundle Table.get_Bundles()' failed.

Assembly 'my_App, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, Public Key Token=null' is marked with the 'Allow Partially Trusted Callers Attribute', and uses the level 2 security transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in 'Allow Partially Trusted Callers' assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already executed the .NET Security Annotator Tool on your assembliy and its dependencies? It guides you through the steps to make it Level 2 compliant.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997356.aspx